# Keep Inputting values until array is full?

Tags: java, arrays, do-loops

I'm creating a class that keeps the scores of quizzes taken by students. Here's the specs:
The constructor is to
a. Create an instance of an int-type array with the length of input parameter. Each
element in the array is initialized as -1.
b. The count is set as 0. It is not the length of array but the number of valid
scores. In other words, the scores is a partially filled array, and the count is
used as an END position of valid scores.
c. Set the name with the second input parameter.

I'm having trouble with the add method. I have to input the size for how many quizzes a student will take and then add the scores for each quiz they took until the array gets full.

Example: If I input the size of the quiz to be 3, I'll be able to add 3 different scores, but if i go over 3 it has to display a message like "Array is full. The value _____ cannot be added".

here's what I have so far for my class:

```
public class Quiz {

    private static int [] scores;
    private  int count;
    private static String name;


    public Quiz (int[] scores, int count, String name){
        int size=0;
        scores=new int [size];
        count=0;
        name=" ";
    }

    public void addScores( int [] scores){
        int size=0;
        scores=new int [size];
        for(int i=0; i<size;i++)
            if(i<size)
               System.out.println(scores[i]);   
            else
                System.out.println("Array is full! the value"+ " " + scores + " "+ "cannot be added.");

}
```

here's part of test driver code  :

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

do {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter a command or type ?");
    String choice;

    choice = in.next().toLowerCase();
    command = choice.charAt(0);
    switch (command) {
        case 'n':
            System.out.println("[Create a new data]");
            System.out.println("[Input the size of quizzes]:"+ " ");
            int size=in.nextInt();
            String linebreak = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("[Input the name of student]:"+ " ");
            String name=in.nextLine();

            break;

        case 'a':
            System.out.println("a [Add a score]:"+ " ");{

            int i=0;            
            i=in.nextInt();

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does this constructor `public Quiz (int[] scores, int count, String name)` require some arguments, if it doesn't use them? Next thing: `scores=new int [size];` ... `size` was set to `0`, so allows `0` entries ... not very useful, don't you think? And the last thing (for now): wouldn't it make more sense to use the existing array in method `addScores` instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Two observations: 1) You probably want to change some lines in your constructor to look more like `this.count = count;`, if you're adopting the very normal idiom of initialising a field to one of the constructor arguments.

Comment: 2) You almost certainly don't want `name` or `scores` to be static.  They definitely belong to an individual `Quiz` instance!  Otherwise, if a second Quiz is created anywhere else in the code, suddenly the first Quiz's names and scores will be updated.  That defeats the whole purpose of having objects...

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code in your `addScores` method. Your passing it an int array `scores` but your setting its value to a new array of size 0. You need to omit the following line:

```
 scores=new int [size];
```

And you need to set your size variable to size of the incoming array.

```
 int size = scores.length;
```

Comment: No need to leave a comment - this is an answer (and a correct one AFAICT).

Comment: This is great. I would add (because I don't want to make a separate answer, you can edit yours if you'd like) that OP can even change their code to avoid the if/else block in the for loop. Since we know the for loop will go the entire length of the array, they can just have the first print function inside the for loop. Then, when the loop is done, they can say it is full and print the value.